# Android: Create List<Map<String, List<ObjectType>>

Tags: java, android

Can someone help me solve my problem, how to create `List<Map<Integer, List<MyType>>` in while cycle. I'm selecting data from database and I'd like to add objects, that accomplish select's where condition into List and then put it into `Map<Integer, List<MyType>` where map key is in my case integer from database column order_num. Finally I would like to add all created maps into List. Method's return value is `List<Map<Integer, List<MyType>>>`.

Here's my part of source:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext) {
       int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_id"));
       int orderNum = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("order_num"));
       String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("item_name"));

       list.add(new Item(id, orderNum, name);
   }
```

now I'd like to add this list into Map where key is `orderNum` and value is `List<Item>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd declare an orderNum variable outside the loop so you can use it when the loop finishes:

```
int orderNum;
for ( cursor.moveToFirst; !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext )
{
    int id = cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( "item_id" ) );
    orderNum = cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( "order_num" ) );
    String name = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( "item_name" ) );

    list.add( new Item( id, orderNum, name ) );
}

map.put( orderNum, list );
```

I guess that whole block will be in some sort of loop too, so when that loop finishes then you can do

```
masterList.add( map );
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to add to the map inside the loop? Otherwise you are only adding one data set to the map instead of each row from DB. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: As I understood the question, the loop he has creates a list of data sets from the database query, then he wants to add that list to a map, each entry of which corresponds to one of his queries.

Comment: +1 for probably being right :) I wasn't sure which way the OP was wanting to do it so I made the suggestion just in case

Answer (score 0):

Ty using a hashmap instead. I'm not sure if this work, but you can at least try it.

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>>();
```

Maybe this helps as well:
http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/javahashmap.shtml